# Visualforce commandLink not working when opening in new tab

Tags: visualforce, javascript, redirect

I have this commandLink in my visualforce page

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!Order.Name}" onclick="window.top.location='/{!Order.id}';"/>
```

When I simply left click the link it redirects just fine.

However, when I right click and click "open link in new tab" I get this error in the new window.
[[image: URl No longer exists error]
How do I allow the link to be opened in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix, you gotta use a outputLink instead of a commandLink

For the commandLink:

`<apex:commandLink value="{!Order.Name}" onclick="window.top.location='/{!Order.id}';"/>`

I used this outputLink:

`<apex:outputLink onclick="window.top.location=('/{!o.id}');" value="/{!o.Id}">{!o.Name}</apex:outputLink>`

The reason I have onclick is because my VF page is imbedded in a page layout and I want to completely redirect to a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting `target="_blank"` property in `apex:commandLink`.

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!Order.Name}" target="_blank" 
    onclick="window.top.location='/{!Order.id}';"/>
```

You can also try using URLFOR to protect from implementation detail.

```
 <apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.Order.View, o.Id)}" 
 value="{!o.Name}" target="_blank" />
```

Comment: `target="_blank"` forces the link to open in a new tab. I want the link on left click to be in the current tab, and when you right click>"open in new tab" it opens in a new tab.

Comment: you can use target="_self" which will open in current tab.

Comment: Yeah it does doesn't it. But it still throws and error when you right click> open in new tab